# How to make a modal toggle only when navigating from a specific page in React Native?

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, modal-dialog, react-navigation

I have two screens in my app called "ReadyScreen" and "RunningScreen."

The user can access ReadyScreen on one of two ways:

1: When they are getting ready to start a run (when they click the start run button)

2: When they finish the run, they will be navigated from RunningScreen back to the ReadyScreen.

When the user finishes a run, i want a modal to toggle showing them:

How Many Steps They Ran, Average HR, etc.

but I only want it to toggle when they are navigating from "RunningScreen."

Would this require an "if" statement basically stating if they navigated from RunningScreen the modal will toggle, else, it will not? Or is there more nuance to this?

Answer (score 0):

i would send a route param in RunningScreen:

```
navigation.navigate('ReadyScreen', {
 didComeFromRunningScreen: true
})
```

then in RunningScreen get the variable:

```
const RunningScreen = ({ route }) => {
 const { didComeFromRunningScreen } = route.params

 useEffect(() => {
  if(didComeFromRunningScreen){
   //show modal
  }
 }, [])
}
```

i believe this should work.

Comment: If I am already using:

const RunningScreen = ({ navigation}) => {

to navigate from RunningScreen to ReadyScreen, will I need to modify this to be "route" instead?

Comment: @MK_Pierce no you just need to receive the route in the screen you send data to.

Comment: For clarity, do I put all of this code in the "RunningScreen" or should the first part go into "RunningScreen" and the second part go in "ReadyScreen?"

Comment: In addition, how to I make sure that it is actually receive the routing properly?

Comment: @MK_Pierce check this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/. its pretty simple to send data as route params

Comment: So if I had a MainTabStackScreen that holds all of the info that as to what is in this particular stack navigator, would it go in there? Or would it go in the individual files?

Comment: @MK_Pierce if you want access to all info from any screen its not recommended to send them as route params through the entire app. in that case i would save it in redux, then you can easily pull the data wherever you need it.

Comment: I am still a little confused on how to pass the data from my RunningScreen to my ReadyScreen

Comment: @MK_Pierce check this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/ its very simple